# Is Monopolium Theoretically Stable?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-monopoles, grand-unification

*Monopolium* is the hypothetical composite of either (1) a north-south pair of monopoles, or (2) a magnetic monopole that has captured an atomic nucleus, analogous to how atomic nuclei capture electrons. My question concerns (2) and to be specific, the capture of an Aluminum-27 nucleus.

In *Monopole ‘83*, it is discussed and mathematically shown on [pgs. 333-37](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-0375-7_30) that (theoretically) Al-27 nuclei can be captured by monopoles, with a resulting ionization energy of ~560 keV.

**Question:** Is this configuration (theoretically) stable, and if so, can this kind of monopolium be able to form a bond with another “atom” of monopolium, in a similar way to how ordinary atoms can form molecules, as a *stable* monopolium “molecule”?